# As a good practice, should Laravel controllers be resource based or view based?

Tags: laravel

I'd like to know if there is a good practice out there regarding Laravel controllers.

> Should they be resource-based or view-based?

To be clearer, what I mean by a resource is a single entity in the application, e.g. User, Blog, Comment, Payment, etc. and what I mean by view is a page/ screen that the user sees.

Additionally, a view could display multiple resources all mixed together, for example let's say an 'Accounts' view which would show different resources such as

1. all volunteers pending to be paid (Volunteer resource)
2. recent payments (Payment resource)
3. recent tasks paid (Task resource), etc.

So, is it a better practice to have a controller for all of the aforementioned resources and then fetch them separately (tasks, volunteers and payments separately) or rather have a controller for the 'Accounts' view where one request would return all the data necessary to be displayed on the page?

Any advice would be helpful!

Comment: I think it depends on the need, Usually we use resource based(specially in CRUD). I do not think that view based is the right thing to do as in all cases it's just a resource which is related with another resource.

You may need to mix both of them use the resource based as your main way to build your app and use view based in shared parts, you may separate them

Answer (score 0):

There is not really a "right" way for you to construct your controller, it is entirely contextual.

My rule of thumb is to try to follow the `SOLID` principles and review the controller i'm building.

---

**Good**

In your example, I would probably create an `AccountController` as a Resource Controller and return the `Account` with it's related models as part of the `show` view:

```
public function show(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Account::with(['volunteers','payments','tasks'])->find(1);
    
    return view('accounts.show', [
        'account' => $account
    ]);
}
```

This makes sense as the `AccountController` is responsible for returning an `Account`.

---

**Bad**

However, something like this would be a bad idea

```
public function showAccount(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Account::find(1);
    
    return view('accounts.show', [
        'account' => $account
    ]);
}

public function showPayments(Request $request, $id)
{
    $payments = Payment::where('account_id', $id)->get();
    
    return view('payments.show', [
        'payments' => $payments
    ]);
}
```

This would make the `AccountController` responsible for returning `Payment`'s which doesn't make sense. In this case i would split the controllers and have a `PaymentController`

Comment: I don't have a model for 'Account'. As in, 'account' is nothing except a view where the user can see accounts related details of an organization. So, it's not like as if an account is linked to volunteers, tasks or payments. Let me know if that makes it clear.

Comment: Why not make an `Account` model or use the standard `User` model? Having these relationships has massive benefits and would give you access to things like query scopes, etc, etc